Playing .webm video files in a hover-provider in a vscode extension
I've written a extension for my own language of my game. I already have a hover provider with various features For example hovering over lines like setImage(Assets/Img/foo) in vscode will preview the image from the local workspace in a hover provider. The same I want to do for videos on lines like setAnimation(Assets/Ani/bar) where it should play the video in the hover provider. This works well for .mp4 files but not for .webm files.
Is there a way to make it work?
I know I can play the video in a webview but I don't want to open the video in another tab or anything. It should just be a quick in-line preview.
I don't want to make a conversion from webm to mp4 at runtime too make it work because it obviously takes too long.
This is my working code for .mp4 files:
          ...
          var filePath = resourcesDir + "\\Animations\\" + text + ".mp4";
          const videoUri = vscode.Uri.file(filePath);
          contents = new vscode.MarkdownString(
            ` <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                <source src="${videoUri}" type="video/mp4">
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
             </video>`
        );
        contents.isTrusted = true;
        contents.supportHtml = true;
        return new vscode.Hover(contents);

If I rename both occasions of "mp4" to "webm". I get an endless loading loop in the player.
The same happens if I try to open the .webm files as .mp4 files.
I couldn't find any information or documentation why this doesn't work for .webm but for mp4. The underlying engine for rendering the html markup (presumable chromium) should be able to handle .webm, no? Do I oversee something trivial?
